# How to Control div enabled/disabled with parameter from code behinde in ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: html, asp.net

How I can control div enabled/disabled with send parameter from code behide? This is my code:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="<%# collapseOneValue%>">Question?</a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div id="<%#Eval(collapseOneTitle)%>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        Answer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: having your id be a code behind variable will not accomplish what you are tryig to do.

Please show your code behind logic

Answer (score 0):

You can only Modify Serverside controls from Code behind . `<div>`tag is just a Basic Html control .
Instead of `<div>` tag u should use `asp:Panel` control, then u will be able to modify this.

```
<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="gainsboro" Height="200px" Width="300px">

//contect

       </asp:Panel>
```

asp:Panel is a DIV when it gets rendered